# How can I trigger a pagetransition on scroll/ keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, parallax

For a client we need to create an experience. We are thinking of creating the experience with full body page/ element transitions like:

- http://beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayH6

Question, is there a library why is responsible for this behavior or is it all custom build?

2 more examples of the scroll effect, though the text effects are missing here:

- http://onlinedepartment.nl/#cases
- http://www.apple.com/ipad-air/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a plugin for this `fullPage.js`  http://cube3x.com/2013/10/fullpage-js-create-beautiful-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/

Comment: Nice! though no text transitions, is that correct? ps. the demo link does not work.

Comment: Did you see the text transitions? do you know anything which does that as well?

Comment: i didn't get you which text transitions?

Comment: check http://beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayH6#headphone-portraits and then scroll down one window. You see the text is coming in later.

Comment: @Kim  that technique is called as `lazy loading` there are also plugins for that like http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/. you can also give that effect by your own, you have to hide some elements on pageload and then after some specific delay you can call a function(s) to load(show) hidden elements in the required order like one by one, or group wise, and in desired way like sliding down, fading in, imploding etc

Comment: @Kim You can use the callbacks in the fullPage.js plugin `onLeave` or `afterLoad` to create those animations or dynamic load.

Comment: @Kim that text on second page `SECTION 1` slides in when scrolled to that part but it remains there after. You have to make that element again disappear when the user scroll to other parts so that every time user scroll he/she can see the text animate.

Comment: @UDB Thanks! that will do the job! Also see http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

Comment: @UDB, as i said, you can use the events `onLeave` and `afterLoad`. In order to make it disappear again, use `onLeave`. You can play a lot with those events, it depends on your imagination.

Answer (score 0):

This library can also be used:

http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html